# File Handling + character manipulation

Tags: c

this is my code.

the input numbers are

1234567890

the output of this code should be

(123)456-7890

but the output is different. Any advice or error fixes in my code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
    char ch;
    int a[100], s[100], str, k, i;
    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen("number.c", "r");
    while ( ( ch = fgetc(fp) ) != EOF )
    {
        k = 0;
        a[k] = '(';
        a[k+4] = ')';
        a[k+8] = '-';
        for (i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++)
        {
            if (isdigit(s[i]))
            {
                a[k++] = s[i];
                if (k == 3)
                {
                    k++;
                }
            }
            printf("%s", a);
        }
        fclose(fp);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: My advice: don't write code that executes undefined behavior, like reading `s[i]` does while the array's contents are uninitialized.

Comment: Looks like you missed  space for "-". Try if(k==3 || k == 7)   {   k++;   } instead of if(k==3)  {  k++;  }

Comment: Sure you can, @ameyCU.  *Reading* array elements before they have been initialized produces undefined behavior, but you can *write* to any subset of the array elements, in any order.

Comment: You never use the characters you read. Looks like you either intended to store the characters you read in `s`, or intended to read a whole string into `s`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger  Ohh  sorry then ,never really gave it a thought . Thanks for correcting me !! :)

Comment: @molbdnilo what do you mean?

Comment: @HorlicVince, molbdnilo is pointing out that although you declare array `s`, you never initialize it with anything.  You are reading data from your file a character at a time, into variable `ch`.  That is the variable that contains the next character to analyze, not `s[i]`.  Moreover, your inner `for` loop is therefore bogus.  The outer `while` loop covers all the iteration you need -- at least for handling a single line, which is all your code is set up to do.

Comment: @JohnBollinger please bear with me, i just learned file handling yesterday. Can you please help me with this? Sorry, im just a beginner.

Comment: Also you try to print a `int array` with specifier `%s` .

Comment: What happens if your input is `123456789` or `12345678901` or `123cat7890`?

Answer (score 2):

This looks like an assignment from a first year course in CS.  If so, I would say find a TA during office hours and discuss.

There are several issues with the code:

1. Your outer loop is intending to read a line at a time from a file and populate the s array.  It is instead reading a character at a time and populating the ch variable.
2. As mentioned in the comments, you are not accounting for the "-" when putting characters into the a array.
3. You are not terminating your string in the a array.
4. There may be different schools of thought on this in c, but I would make s and a char[] instead of int[].

My advice would be to get out a piece of paper and make spaces for each of your variables.  Then read your code line by line and manipulate your variables the way you expect the computer to execute what is written.  If you can read what is written, rather than what you expect the code to do, then the issues will become apparent.

Comment: There is little room for different schools of thought when it comes to the expected types of `printf()` arguments.  An argument corresponding to a `%s` field descriptor will be interpreted as a `char *`, and `printf()` exhibits undefined behavior if the actual type is incompatible, as the `int *` in the OP's code is.

Answer (score 0):

```
/* ugly: The old phone #
   nice: The formatted phone #
*/
#include <stdio.h>
void fmtpn(const char *ugly, char *nice)
{
    int i, j;
    /* add one to allocate space for null terminator */
    char first3[3 + 1], next3[3 + 1], last4[4 + 1];

    if (strlen(ugly) != 10 || containsalpha(ugly)) {
        strcpy(nice, "Invalid pn!");
        return;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
        first3[i] = ugly[i];
    first3[i] = 0;           /* null terminate the string */

    for (j = 0; j < 3; ++i, ++j)
        next3[j] = ugly[i];
    next3[j] = 0;            /* null terminate */

    for (j = 0; j < 4; ++i, ++j)
        last4[j] = ugly[i];
    last4[j] = 0;            /* null terminate */

    sprintf(nice, "(%s) %s-%s", first3, next3, last4);
}
```

To read from the file:

```
FILE *fp;
char ugly[32], good[32];
if (fp = fopen("file", "r")) {
    fgets(ugly, 32, fp);
    fmtpn(ugly, good);
    puts(good);
}
```

Comment: ^ Where is the file handling setting here?

Answer (score 0):

You have other options aside from looping through your sting to build the phone number. Sometimes, when dealing with fixed strings or known quantities, a straight forward packing of the characters into a fixed format is a lot simpler than picking the characters out of loops.

For example, here you know you are dealing with a `10 char` string of digits. In your code you can read/parse each line into a string of 10 digits. Then your only task is to format those 10 digits into the phone number. Using a pointer for each string and then `strncpy` is about as easy as anything else:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void) {

    char *digits = "1234567890";
    char *p = digits;

    char phonenum[15] = {0};
    char *pf = phonenum;

    /* build formatted phone number */
    *pf++ = '(';
    strncpy (pf, p, 3);
    pf += 3, p += 3;
    *pf++ = ')';
    *pf++ = ' ';        /* note: included space, remove line if unwanted */
    strncpy (pf, p, 3);
    pf += 3, p += 3;
    *pf++ = '-';
    strncpy (pf, p, 4);
    pf += 4;
    *pf = 0;

    printf ("\n digits : %s\n phone  : %s\n\n", digits, phonenum);

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
$ ./bin/phnumbld

 digits : 1234567890
 phone  : (123) 456-7890
```

You can easily turn the code above into a simple function that creates a formatted phone number given any 10-digit string. Breaking your code down into functional pieces not only makes your code easier to read and write, but it also builds flexibility and ease of maintenance into your code. Here were you dealing with an actual dial-string that included the international dialing prefix and country code, you could easily format the last 10 digits of the longer string by using a pointer to the appropriate beginning character.

**With File Handling**

Writing anything in C is no different. You simply break the problem down into discrete operations and then write small bits of code to handle each part of the problem. As you get more experience, you will build a collection of routines to handle most situations.

Below the code declare three constants. `ACPN` (area code phone number length), `MAXC` (maximum digits in dial string including country code and international dialing prefix), and `MAXS` (maximum number of chars in line to read from file)

You options for reading lines of data in C are broken into two broad categories, **character oriented input** and **line oriented input**. When reading lines from a file, in most cases **line oriented input** is the proper choice. You read a line of data at a time into a buffer, then you parse the information you need from the buffer. Your primary choices for line oriented input in C are `fgets` and `getline`. We use the standard `fgets` below.

Below, the code will read a line of data, then call `get_n_digits` to extract up to `MAXC` digits in the line into a separate buffer holding the digits (`numstr`). The number string is then passed to `fmt_phone` which takes the last 10 digits in the string (discarding any initial country-code or int'l dialing prefix) and formatting those digits into a telephone number format. You can adjust any part as needed to meet your input file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define ACPN 10
#define MAXC 16
#define MAXS 256

size_t strip_newline (char *s);
char *get_n_digits (char *numstr, char *s, size_t n);
char *fmt_phone (char *fmts, char *s, size_t n);

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    /* open file or read from stdin */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;
    if (!fp) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: failed to open file for reading\n");
        return 1;
    }

    char numstr[MAXC] = {0};    /* string of digits (max MAXC - 1)  */
    char fmtstr[MAXC] = {0};    /* formatted phone number string    */
    char line[MAXS] = {0};      /* line buffer holding full line    */

    /* read each line from fp (up to MAXS chars) */
    while (fgets (line, MAXS, fp))
    {
        size_t len = strip_newline (line);  /* strip trailing newline       */
        get_n_digits (numstr, line, MAXC);  /* get MAXC digits from line    */
        printf ("\n read  : %s  (%zu chars), taking last 10 of : %s\n",
                line, len, numstr);

        /* format last 10 digits into phone number */
        fmt_phone (fmtstr, numstr, ACPN);
        printf (" phone : %s\n", fmtstr);
    }

    if (fp != stdin) fclose (fp);

    return 0;
}

size_t strip_newline (char *s)
{
    size_t len = strlen (s);
    s [--len] = 0;

    return len;
}

/* extract upto n digits from string s, copy to numstr */
   char *get_n_digits (char *numstr, char *s, size_t n)
{
    char *p = s;
    size_t idx = 0;
    while (*p && idx < n - 1) {
        if (*p >= '0' && *p <= '9')
            numstr[idx++] = *p;
        p++;
    }
    numstr[idx] = 0;

    return numstr;
}

/* format last n (10) digits in s into a formatted
   telephone number: (xxx) yyy-zzzz, copy to fmts.
   'last 10' accounts for country code and international
   dialing prefix at beginning of dial string.
*/
char *fmt_phone (char *fmts, char *s, size_t n)
{
    /* validate strings */
    if (!fmts || !s) {
        fprintf (stderr, "%s() error: invalid string parameter.\n", __func__);
        *fmts = 0;
        return fmts;
    }

    /* validate length of n */
    if (n < ACPN) {
        fprintf (stderr, "%s() error: insufficient size 'n' for format.\n", __func__);
        *fmts = 0;
        return fmts;
    }

    /* validate length of s */
    size_t len = strlen (s);
    if (len < n) {
        fprintf (stderr, "%s() error: insufficient digits in string.\n", __func__);
        *fmts = 0;
        return fmts;
    }

    /* set start pointer to last 10 digits */
    char *p = len > n ? s + len - n : s;
    char *pf = fmts;

    /* build formatted phone number */
    *pf++ = '(';
    strncpy (pf, p, 3);
    pf += 3, p += 3;
    *pf++ = ')';
    *pf++ = ' ';
    strncpy (pf, p, 3);
    pf += 3, p += 3;
    *pf++ = '-';
    strncpy (pf, p, 4);
    pf += 4;
    *pf = 0;

    return fmts;
}
```

Compile with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -o progname sourcename.c`

**Example Input**

```
$ cat dat/pnumtest.txt
123456789012345
12345678901234
1234567890123
123456789012
12345678901
1234567890
123456789
```

**Example Output**

```
$ ./bin/phnum dat/pnumtest.txt

 read  : 123456789012345  (15 chars), taking last 10 of : 123456789012345
 phone : (678) 901-2345

 read  : 12345678901234  (14 chars), taking last 10 of : 12345678901234
 phone : (567) 890-1234

 read  : 1234567890123  (13 chars), taking last 10 of : 1234567890123
 phone : (456) 789-0123

 read  : 123456789012  (12 chars), taking last 10 of : 123456789012
 phone : (345) 678-9012

 read  : 12345678901  (11 chars), taking last 10 of : 12345678901
 phone : (234) 567-8901

 read  : 1234567890  (10 chars), taking last 10 of : 1234567890
 phone : (123) 456-7890

 read  : 123456789  (9 chars), taking last 10 of : 123456789
fmt_phone() error: insufficient digits in string.
 phone :
```

**Note:** there are many, many different ways to approach this problem, this is but one.

**Note2:** while not required for this code, I included a function showing how to strip the trailing `newline` (`'\n'`) from the input read by `fgets`. It is never a good idea to leave `newlines` dangling from strings in your code. While here they would not have caused a problem, in most cases they will bite you if your are not aware of them. So get in the practice of handling/removing the trailing newlines when using `fgets` or `getline` to read from a file. (note: `getline` provides the number of characters actually read as its return, so you can avoid calling `strlen` and simply use the return of `getline` to remove the newline in that case.)

Answer (score 0):

No love for sscanf?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int prettyprint(char *input, char *output)
{
    int n[10], ret;
    ret = sscanf(input, "%1d%1d%1d%1d%1d%1d%1d%1d%1d%1d", &(n[0]), &(n[1]),
    &(n[2]), &(n[3]), &(n[4]), &(n[5]), &(n[6]),
    &(n[7]), &(n[8]), &(n[9]));
    if (ret != 10)
        fprintf(stderr, "invalid input\n");

    sprintf(output, "(%1d%1d%1d) %1d%1d%1d-%1d%1d%1d%1d",
    n[0], n[1], n[2],
    n[3],n[4], n[5],
    n[6], n[7], n[8], n[9]);
    return 0;
}
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char digits[] = "0123456789";
    char output[256];
    prettyprint(digits, output);
    printf("%s\n", output);
}
```

Comment: No, you can figure out that part of your homework on your own.